Jacob's Ladder with 2 kV MOT inductance on microcontroller
A 2 kV transformer wired to steel rods exhibits expected arcing when the arc is manually started by shorting the rods with a length of wire attached to an insulted stick from a distance.
Getting the arc to begin at the shortest distance on the rods is challenging with the limited voltage. Adding a stepper motor with an insulated shaft that swipes a length of wire across the rods very briefly one time per rotation causes expected arcing as if it were done with the stick.
The problem: the MCU spontaneously resets when the rods short and the motor controller no longer receives instructions resulting in motor stoppage at the exact point where the rods are shorted.
Suspect Possibilities:

The RESET pin of the MCU is held high with a pull up resistor and
there is a momentary contact button with a capacitor to help
eliminate bounce.

The USB cable length inducts interference causing the MCU to reset.

Lack of shielding.


Preferably, avoiding learning things the hard way. What can be done to prevent this? Should the whole thing be scrapped and up the voltage?

Any schematic to share?

This will be an EMC problem.  Understand that EMC is a complex, interconnected topic, and EMC problems are holistic in nature.  There is generally very little that can be said about a problem without also completely describing the setup and environment: schematics, PCB layout and photos are most likely required for a reasonably complete and confident answer.

Why just 2 kV? Easy to find or make a source for 10 or 20 kV, a much more satisfying arc length and self-starting.

@DrMoishePippik 'easy' is a four letter word. What may be easy for you may be less so for our OP. I used 6 MOTs in series for my Jacob's.

@DrMoishePippik ... and then it needed a Gabriel Gap to get stable performance

use an 'old skool' brushed DC motor, very resistant to EMC

A) use a longer insulating shaft on the stepper motor
B) use a synchronous gear motor, instead of a stepper motor.
(you might find such a motor driving the turntable in a microwave oven)
